# Loading the same UserControl interfering with one another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a `user control` that is being loaded 2 times on the same page. I'm trying to hide a button and label in one of the user controls and only show them after a button click, on the other I need them all to be invisible.
Clicking the button makes the controls freak out, disables one of the buttons and shows all the controls it should shown on 1 to both controls.
How can I stop this from happening?

the 2 controls

```
<bs:InsuranceCond runat="server" ID="InsuranceCondFC" ClientIDMode="Static" Version="1" Visible="true" />
<bs:InsuranceCond runat="server" ID="InsuranceCondKK" ClientIDMode="Static" Version="1" Visible="true" />
```

This is what I've got so far.
In the .aspx page:

```
protected void insuranceControlCheck()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() != "-1")
    {

        InsuranceCondFC.hideFC();
    }
}
```

In the .ascx control:

```
 public void hideFC()
{
    if (this.ID.ToString() == "InsuranceCondFC")
    {
        trNoData.Visible = false;
        btnAddLine.Visible = false;
        trAddData.Visible = false;
    }
    if (this.ID.ToString() == "InsuranceCondKK")
    {
        trNoData.Visible = true;
        btnAddLine.Visible = true;
        trAddData.Visible = false;
    }

    UpdatePanelInsuranceCond.Update();
}

protected void btnAddLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ID.ToString() == "InsuranceCondFC")
    {
        trNoData.Visible = false;
        btnAddLine.Visible = false;
        trAddData.Visible = false;
    }
    if (this.ID.ToString() == "InsuranceCondKK")
    {
        trNoData.Visible = false;
        btnAddLine.Visible = true;
        trAddData.Visible = true;
    }

    UpdatePanelInsuranceCond.Update();
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

`AvailableCheck` is a hiddenfield I used since I was having the same problem with using the `(this.ID.ToString() == "Id of the control")`

Comment: Did you debug the code and checked if the code works as per the logic?

Comment: The page was going through postbacks, so the hiddenfield value kept going back to 0. I'll test again with the id's. Updated the question.

Comment: It goes through the logic, but doesn't show the results it should.